# Why the compiler can overload functions with passing by reference and passing by value

Tags: c++, function, reference, overloading

I thought that during overloading, compiler checks whether the formal arguments are of the same type. For example:

```
void a(int x)
void a(double x)
```

can overload simply because the two "x"s have the difference type.

However, does the following two have the different type?

```
void f(int y)
void f(int& y)
```

I understand that one is PBV and the other PBR. But the second y has the type "int" as well right? Why it compiles successfully?

P.S.
I notice that although it compiles, it does not run though, reporting run-time error of ambiguity.

Comment: `int` and `int&` are two distinct types.

Comment: ambiguity will be always at compile time. what do you mean by run time ambiguity?

Comment: @Chubsdad I presume he means that if you call `f(value)` how does it know if you want to pass by reference or by value and as such how is it determined which overload of `f ` is called

Comment: @mathematician1975, that's compile time error, not runtime as OP says

Comment: can you post/describe your runtime error?

Answer (score 8):

Broadly speaking functions can be overloaded on the basis of:

- Number of arguments
- *Type* of arguments
- Sequence of arguments

The example compiles because it satisfy's the second criteria.
`int` and `int &` are different *data types*.

---

Consider the following example:

```
void foo(int i);
void foo(int& i);
void foo(int i){}
void foo(int& i){}
int main()
{
     return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles because it is valid code. Depending on what function argument is passed to the function the compiler may/may not detect the best match for the function call. So the functions themselves are allowed to co-exist but their usage in certain ways may cause ambiguity for the compiler.

For example:
In the following code, a literal cannot be bound to a non-const reference and hence the only candidate for function call is the non reference version and this should compile and work just fine:

```
void foo(int i);
void foo(int& i);
void foo(int i){}
void foo(int& i){}
int main()
{
    foo(20); 
    return 0;
}
```

But,

```
void foo(int i);
void foo(int& i);
void foo(int i){}
void foo(int& i){}
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    foo(i);
    return 0;
}
```

the above will cause ambiguity for the compiler because compiler cannot detect the best match between the two function calls.

Comment: is there a data type called int &?. & is not part of the declaration specifier but is part of the declarator I guess

Comment: @Chubsdad: There's definitely a type "reference to int", and `int&` is the canonical name for it. How the compiler parses the declaration is another matter.

Comment: My impression of it is that this means that `void foo(int& i)` can be called if passed an int literal or a const int variable, but `void foo(int i)` cannot be called _at all_ in this case.  You'd think some sort of optimizer would notice this and warn you that you have a function that can never be called under any circumstances?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: No, only a const reference can bind to an literal and for that to happen the function declaration would have to be `void foo(const int& i)`

Comment: @AlokSave: Okay, but `void foo(int i)` still cannot be called at all, right?  Just wondering why the compiler doesn't catch that and let you know you've got an un-callable function.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: In the second case, both functions are a good match.If you comment out either the other function will get called. There is no un-callable function. If either was uncallable the ambiguity situation would not arise.Or Perhaps, I do not understand your comment correctly?

Comment: @AlokSave: I mean that the existence of both functions means that one of them can never be called.  Obviously if you commented one of them out, the other could be called.  But since both are there, it means that one of them is un-callable, and therefore useless code.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, ambiguety is ALWAYS reported at compile time.

Secondly, whether your example compiles or not depends on how you use this function

```
void f(int y)
{
}
void f(int& y)
{
}


int main ()
{
    int a = 10;

    f (a); // ERROR: ambiguous call
    f (10); // OK
}
```

In the first case there is an error, becasue `a` can be passed as both copy and reference.
In the second case there will be no error, because `int` literal cannot be passed by non-const reference

Answer (score 2):

That depends. If you don't call these functions from your code, the compiler might optimize them away. If it doesn't, you can open the .obj file with a text viewer and search for the function name  (give it a more unique name than `f`, e.g. `floop` :-)), you will see two mangled names using your basic function name.

But if you do try to use them then you will notice a difference. If you call

```
f(5);
```

The the compiler can use only the `f(int y)` version, because it's impossible to pass a constant by reference. But if you do

```
int b = 10;
f(b);
```

Then the compiler will issue an amibuity error, since both `f` forms can be called this way.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the call f(x) where x is an int.

> $13.3.3.1.4 - "When a parameter of reference type binds directly
>   (8.5.3) to an argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is
>   the identity conversion, unless the argument expression has a type
>   that is a derived class of the parameter type, in which case the
>   implicit conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion"

Therefore f(int &) is an exact match and so is f(int) as both are identity conversions. Therefore ambiguity

Now Let's take the call 'f(2)'

This is fine because 'f(int &)' is not a match at all as rvalues don't bind to non-const lvalues. Therefore, no ambiguity

So, the standard allows 'f(T)' abd 'f(T &)' to form an overload set.

Comment: The standard actually allows any pair of functions to form an overload set, even if they would be ambiguous for all possible arguments. It's just not feasible to check for potential ambiguity, whereas it's easy to detect an actual ambiguity given specific arguments.

Comment: @MSalter: I was referring to the specific examples in $13.1/2. They give compilation error even if not used

Comment: Actually, the last example is not an error. The examples which do have an error are not ambiguous but equivalent. Subtle distinction, but important. With two equivalent declarations, you're referring to a single function.